# get parameters from android virtual devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I make a device in android virtual device manager (UI), can I get the parameters to create these device in comand line?.

for example, to get these from a existing emulator

```
android create avd -n Ev o4G -t 9 -c 8000MB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks friends for the help they gave me, but I finally found the answer. In each emulator created by avd, the parameters used are stored in the file:

```
.android/avd/your_emulator_name.avd/config.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Check the [Managing AVDs from commandline](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) which will provide you varieties of commands you can use.

e.g.

```
android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID> [-<option> <value>]
```

**UPDATE**

To get the current detailed list of AVDs simply put:

```
android list targets
```

For more specific explanation, please check the link I posted.

Comment: sorry friend, but this not respond the question. ¿can I get the parameters for command line from one emulator created in avd ui?

Comment: @GuillermoTobar yes, you can. Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: the method "android list targets" not respond the question, please see my updated example.

Comment: @GuillermoTobar sorry buddy, still can't get what you want. You want to know the available options when you creating the AVDs from commandline? the available options you can use to create AVDs are available on the link I provided.